# Integrating Factorials

Tags: integration, factorial

I feel like I'm doing something wrong here: $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^n)=n!$$

$$ 5!=\frac{d^5}{dx^5}(x^5)$$

$$ \int{5! dx}=\int{\frac{d^5}{dx^5}(x^5)}dx=x\frac{d^4}{dx^4}(x^4)=x*4!$$

Please explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you pull out an $x$, shouldn't you be left with $\frac{d^4}{dx^4}(x^5)$?

Comment: The integral of a product is hardly ever the product of the integrals.

Comment: The calculation there is correct. It is not the same as yours.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Then the answer is $x*5!$

Comment: Plus $C$, as usual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ \int{5! dx}=\int{\frac{d^5}{dx^5}(x^5)}dx=\frac{d^4}{dx^4}(x^5)=x*5!$$

$$ \int 120 dx = 120*x$$

*Thanks Cocopuffs

Answer (score -1):

$ \int{5! dx}=\int{\frac{d^5}{dx^5}(x^5)}dx=5\frac{d^4}{dx^4}(x^4)=5*4! $

Comment: $\frac{d^5}{dx^5}(x^5)=5*\frac{d^4}{dx^4}(x^4)=5!$ $therefore \int \frac{d^5}{dx^5}(x^5)4$ can't equal $5*\frac{d^4}{dx^4}(x^4)$

Comment: why? Simplify further you will end up getting 5*4*3*2*1 which is same as 5!